# How can I up sound volume of my mic?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

It seems simple, but it doesn't work for me.

If I load alsamixer for the first time I see that the device has no controls at all. If I press F5 CAPTURE appears.

I can't record fine audio. When I record something my voice is too quiet in Discord or Telegram or any browser chat.

BUT I try test record

```
$> arecord --duration=5 --format=dat --device=plughw:3,0 test-mic.wav
```

I hear the great quality and clean loud voice!

The question is simple what should I use to increase the volume of the microphone?

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

```sh
>  arecord -L

hw:CARD=M13,DEV=0
    M13, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=M13,DEV=0
    M13, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=M13
    M13, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=M13,DEV=0
    M13, USB Audio
    Front output / input
dsnoop:CARD=M13,DEV=0
    M13, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
usbstream:CARD=M13
    M13
    USB Stream Output
```

[image]